# How do I submit apps to the Apple AppStore when they they use Facebook's IDFA

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My iOS app uses Facebook's API which apparently uses an IDFA, that iTunes Connect didn't use to check for. I am told:
Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA).
Which (options) should I check:
I do not serve any advertisements from my app.

Answer (score 1):

This is my recommended process:

- Introduce a banner, that you can later disable.
- Leave it enabled till review of your app has been completed.

This way, you only have to check the case "my app shows ads". Showing ads is extremely common. And IDFA is an ID for advertisers.

Other solutions may work as well, but this one has been tested and I think it's the best way to keep a low profile, since review is performed by humans and we don't know what to expect from the review process (i.e. it's a black box process).

Hope this helps